# How can I change the size of a Dojo button without styling the text?

Tags: css, button, dojo

I'm new to Dojo and CSS, so maybe I'm missing something obvious here.

I have a page with several Dijit buttons that are created programmatically, and I want to make one of them bigger- leave the text alone and increase the space between the text and the edge of the button. I don't want to override the CSS for `.dijiButtonNode` to do so because there are other Dijit buttons the page that shouldn't be altered.

I tried adding this to the widget declaration:

```
style: { padding: "1em" }
```

and this:

```
class: "PaddedButton"

.PaddedButton
{
    padding: 1em;
}
```

but since Dijit buttons are rendered as nested spans it padded the area around the button instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to work with CSS is using one of the browser debugging tools (that you should already be using) like Firebug or the Chrome developer tools. You can find an element's DOM node easily with inspect_element and then directly edit its CSS styles until they do what you want. You can also see what CSS rules are active and what are being ignored or overwritten.

I have come up with a working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/missingno/FrYdx/2/

The important part is the following CSS selector:

```
.paddedButton.dijitButton .dijitButtonNode {
    padding: 1em;
}
```

This selects any node with class dijitButtonNode that descends from a node that has both of the paddedButton and dijitButton classes. I couldn't do just a `.paddedButton .dijitButtonNode` because then the rule would end up being cascaded by a more specific selector.

Comment: Great. I had already made it work in Firebug but I couldn't figure out how I could apply my CSS to that and only that instance of the dijitButtonNode. That selector is what I was missing.